# Jquery Scroll to mask is blocking the functionality of the rest of the page content

Tags: jquery, navigation, scroll

On this page:
http://thegoodgirlsnyc.com/test/new/who.php

I'm working on building a vertical slider.  Several aspects are not working, but most specifically the functionality of the navigation is lost.

This can be shown here:
http://thegoodgirlsnyc.com/test/new/who.php

Should there be a way to fix this by changing the percentages of the mask ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#leftcolumn {
    color: #333333;
    float: left;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 190px;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

added `position:relative` and `z-index:999` and the nav is working again.

I've tried this in Firefox only so there may be a little more tinkering with the positions and z-index's to get it working in IE but you can definitely get this working again with the z-index prperty